# How to read and move read content via SQL into variables within VB.net and use a connectionstring from a module in forms?

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string

This is my first question, by the way - and I'm not sure exactly how to ask, or say what's wrong. There's 3 things I can't sort so any help would be appreciated.
Module:
This and the first (login) form work as they are but I couldn't get either Form to reference con.connectionstring for them to use without having to re-use the string contained in "" (as they do below) - my attempts ended up with errors including saying that the state couldn't be changed as the connection was already open, but I'd like the same one string to be referenced from the Forms.

```
Module ConnectionModule
Public con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Public ds As DataSet = New DataSet

Public Path As String = Application.StartupPath

Public Sub OpenDb()

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=F:\Computing A2\CG4 Coursework\Greener Cleaning\dbCoursework.accdb"
    con.Open()

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        MsgBox("Connection to db not made.")
    End If
End Sub

Public CurrentUser As String = Nothing
End Module
```

The First Form:

```
    Public Class LoginForm


Private Sub LoginForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OpenDb()
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Dim ID As String = txtID.Text
    Dim Pass As String = txtPassword.Text

    If IsNumeric(ID) = False Or ID.Length > 4 Or Pass = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Staff ID is a 4-digit number and Password must not be blank.")
    Else
        Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        OpenDb()
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=F:\Computing A2\CG4 Coursework\Greener Cleaning\dbCoursework.accdb"
        Try
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblStaff WHERE [StaffID]='" & ID & "' AND [Pword] = '" & Pass & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = con
            con.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then 'Correct:
                MenuForm.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                CurrentUser = ID

            Else 'Incorrect:

                MsgBox("Staff ID or Password incorrect.")
                txtPassword.Text = ""
                txtID.Text = ""
                txtID.Focus()

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Database Connection Error.")

        End Try
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

A form to change the password:
The problem here is that lblUser (A clarification for the user to tell them which password will be changed) only outputs the data already within the program as a variable: CurrentUser (as assigned upon successful login). No error is produced but the full name of the user isn't shown (or possibly read from the database).
I'm also unsure how the UPDATE SQL command should be contained within the second procedure, btnAccept_click, here. What the syntax is, basically. I haven't found a clear example to look at.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class PasswordForm

Private Sub PasswordForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=F:\Computing A2\CG4 Coursework\Greener Cleaning\dbCoursework.accdb"

    Dim Returned(2) As String
    CurrentUser = CurrentUser

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Title], [Forename], [Surname] FROM tblStaff WHERE [StaffID]='" & CurrentUser & "'", con)
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            reader.Read()
            'Makes db contents variables            
            Returned(0) = reader.Item("[Title]").ToString
            Returned(1) = reader.Item("[Forename]").ToString
            Returned(2) = reader.Item("[Surname]").ToString
        End If
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Hide()
        MsgBox("Database Connection Error.")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    lblUser.Text = "Current User: " & CurrentUser & Returned(0) & Returned(1) & Returned(2)
    ''Only outputs CurrentUser
End Sub

Private Sub btnAccept_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAccept.Click

    Dim Current As String = txtCurrent.text
    Dim NewPass As String = txtNew.Text

    'Verification
    If txtNew.Text = txtConfirm.Text And NewPass.Length <= 20 Then

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblStaff SET [Pword]='" & NewPass & "' WHERE [StaffID]='" & CurrentUser & "'", con)


    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you, again, for anyone with ideas (especially exact code).
Oh and throughout what's here there are no errors thrown. Just missing content.

Comment: There's a lot of code there and the fact that you say that there's three things that you can't sort out puts me off.  You should address one issue at a time.  The conversation can get very confused otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you are opening the connection in openDB() and you are trying to open it again in form1, this will throw the error you are getting. So comment all the **con** related lines in your form. Same comment for your passowrd form also.

```
'Dim con As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
OpenDb()
'con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=F:\Computing A2\CG4 Coursework\Greener Cleaning\dbCoursework.accdb"
 Try
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblStaff WHERE [StaffID]='" & ID & "' AND [Pword] = '" & Pass & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

        'Open Database Connection
        sqlCom.Connection = con
        'con.Open()
...
end try
```